# setting the size of input fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails form for which I'm trying to change the size of the default fields using either `:size` or both  `:cols => "30", :rows => "10"` as in the code below. However, the form fields are staying the default size. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

```
<%= d.text_field c, :class => 'random', :value => "#{c}", :size => "30", :id => 'correction_data_'"#{c.parameterize}"%>
```

or this way

```
<%= d.text_field @title, :class => 'random', :value => "#{@title}", :cols => "30", :rows => "10", :id => 'correction_data_'"#{@title.parameterize}"%>
```

Comment: Its probably your `random` class that's controlling the size, please post that or check if it has `width` defined.  Also note that `text_field` don't have rows and cols.

Comment: @vinodadhikary I removed the class (which didn't have size controls anyways). I'm using Twitter Bootstrap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`text_field` doesn't consider `rows` and `cols` attributes, but does consider `size` attribute.  `text_area` considers `rows`, `cols` and `size` attributes.

text_field:

```
<%= d.text_field c, :class => 'random', :value => "#{c}", :size => 30, :id => 'correction_data_'"#{c.parameterize}" %>
```

text_area using rows and cols:

```
<%= d.text_area @title, :class => 'random', :value => "#{@title}", :cols => 30, :rows => 10, :id => 'correction_data_'"#{@title.parameterize}" %>
```

text_area using size:

```
<%= d.text_area @title, :class => 'random', :value => "#{@title}", :size => "30x10", :id => 'correction_data_'"#{@title.parameterize}" %>
```